# From iterative to recursive - reordering a list

Tags: python, recursion

I have a list:

```
L = [0,'a','b','c']
```

If I run the following:

```
sortedList = []
while len(L) > 0:
    item = L.pop()
    sortedList.append(item)
print(sortedList)
```

Output:

```
['c', 'b', 'a', 0]
```

As a simple exercise in trying to understand recursion I'd like to put the above in a recursive function. 
I have two attempts - how do I fix one, or both of them - or is there a recursive solution?

1.

```
def extract(Seq):
    if Seq == [0]:
        return s.append(0)
    else:
        extract(Seq[:len(Seq)-1])

        if not s: s = []
        x=Seq.pop()
        return s.append(x)

M = [0,'a','b','c']
print(extract(M))
```

2.

```
def extract2(Seq):
    s=[]
    if Seq:
        return s.append(Seq.pop())
        extract2(Seq)

N = [0,'a','b','c']
print(extract(N))
```

Comment: first of all, avoid using upper case first letter for variables, even more when the variable has a name that can look like a class, it's confusing.

Comment: Find some inspiration with this famous recursive sorting algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: you got here a couple of nice answers here, though to help you actually do it on your own here's a little tip: when you create a recursive algorithm, you usually need to consider three steps: init the recursion ; check the end of recursion condition ; do the recursion. It's not necessarily explicit in the code, and not necessarily in that order, but you need to *think* about those.

Comment: @Ruud I'm doing an Algorithms course using Python .... so have seen inserttion sort, selection sort, merge sort, quick sort, quick search , bogosort ... but I'm still having lots of problems understanding recursive Python: hence the back-to-basics question! Thanks for the tips - much appreciated.

Comment: @Ruud got a feeling that a big problem with the functions in OP is having this additional list `s` ...maybe introducing an additional list is not a good approach when aiming for a recursive solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive solution could be:

```
def extract3(seq):
    if not seq:
        return seq
    return [seq.pop()] + extract3(seq)
```

However this modifies the input list which may not be what you want. So it's better to slice the input list as needed:

```
def extract4(seq):
    if not seq:
        return seq
    return [seq[-1]] + extract4(seq[:-1])
```

where `seq[-1]` means "take the last element of `seq`" and `seq[:-1]` means "take all elements of `seq` except the last one". The function `extract4` builds a new list by taking the elements as needed and without modifying the given sequence `seq`.

You can also use an accumulator which would be called with `extract5(N, [])`:

```
def extract5(seq, acc):
    if not seq:
        return acc
    acc.append(seq[-1])
    return extract5(seq[:-1], acc)
```

Comment: +1 thanks Simeon. My idea in OP of having an additional list `s` is never going to work in a recursive solution? or is it possible to include an additional list?

Comment: @whytheq: I'm not sure where you'd need a variable `s` for. You can include an additional list (called an accumulator) to make the recursion more efficient. But for a basic recursive solution no additional lists or variables are needed.

Comment: thanks Simeon - just out of interest how does `extract5` with an accumulator look - is it an easy addition: in mine they just kept getting overwritten on each recurrence so I'm unsure where the code for an accumulator sits

Comment: @whytheq I have updated the answer with `extract5`. It builds up the final result in the accumulator `acc`.

Comment: ahhh ...excellent - I now see how it keeps track of the additional list ....thanks very much: getting a foothold on this recursive way of thinking is painful (but hopefully worth the effort)

Comment: @whytheq: it is indeed worth the effort as many problems can be solved elegantly with a recursive solution.

Comment: `extract3` is risky because it relies on a specific evaluation order (due to the side effect of `pop`, the left-hand side of `+` _must_ be evaluated before the right-hand side), but the other two functions are excellent renditions of two common styles of recursion: the 'elegant' (`extract4`) and the 'efficient' (`extract5`; the actual performance gain depends on the runtime's _list_ implementation).